# CSS Internal External or Inline Style

Tags: css

I am new to CSS and I wanted to know what is the best practice Internal Style or External Style or Inline Style as a beginner. Please tell me the basic difference also.

Comment: External with a .css Style. You have multiple advantages. You can can use the same stylesheet for all your sites within the website without having to copy the entire styling to other sites. You can use classes to address multiple elements at once instead of copying the same style. Also its easier to see what you did and to adjust it instead of scrolling through your entire html code and see what you have done. Also the use of media queries that help to maintain full responsiveness for mobile use and adjust the usability there. Pretty obvious answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, you can find the differences between the three: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

The most common one on regular websites are external stylesheets. It's the cleanest way because you separate your structure (HTML) from your styles (CSS). Internal CSS is not used a lot when hard coding a website, but it can be legit in some module based architectures. Inline CSS is also used a lot when you work with JavaScript to add styles to elements programmatically.

Edit: as cooskun wrote, the specificity is different between internal/external and inline. Inline get parsed at the end, so it is more specific. With internal and external it depends on which you declare last.

[Please try to Google your question before you post it, I am sure this has been asked before. I am not yet allowed to comment questions]

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is the specificity. I could explain this detailed but it's better to have a look on this fancy website which explains the specificity perfectly.
[CSS Specificity](https://cssspecificity.com/)

The second reason is the code organization. If you prefer inline-style then you can't reuse your code and it makes the code hard to read, hard to maintain, hard to ...

My recommendation, go with external styles. When you have more experience in CSS, you will know where is the best place to use inline styles.